# Troubleshooting ssh connection with RSA key

Tags: linux, centos, rhel, openssh

Here is what I see in the logs

```
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic,password
debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Offering public key: RSA SHA256:f0cjkIUOI7TIxdOW905CdEHDgxNbj1vfXthE2LCz0rk /home/dmytrocx75/.ssh/id_rsa
debug2: we sent a publickey packet, wait for reply
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic,password
debug1: Trying private key: /home/dmytrocx75/.ssh/id_dsa
debug1: Trying private key: /home/dmytrocx75/.ssh/id_ecdsa
debug1: Trying private key: /home/dmytrocx75/.ssh/id_ed25519
debug2: we did not send a packet, disable method
debug1: Next authentication method: password
dmytrocx75@asus's password:
```

Though I followed the procedures described here https://help.ubuntu.com/community/SSH/OpenSSH/Keys#Troubleshooting

Here is server's `/var/log/secure` says

```
Nov  5 18:15:28 Asus sshd[5414]: Authentication refused: bad ownership or modes for file /etc/ssh/dmytrocx75/authorized_keys
Nov  5 18:15:28 Asus sshd[5414]: Failed publickey for root from 192.168.1.3 port 49982 ssh2: RSA SHA256:f0cjkIUOI7TIxdOW905CdEHDgxNbj1vfXthE2LCz0rk
```

Comment: You seem to have forgotten a question. What are you actually asking?

Comment: It's obvious that I was asking how to solve the "Authentication refused" problem. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Actually, no, is not automatically obvious. You could have been asking that. But you could also have been asking why on earth you had to put your keys under `/etc/ssh` instead of in your home directory. Or you might have an account with no password and you're trying to get `ssh` to let you log in. Or even something else. It's always best to ask an explicit question, and that's why the close text says, "_As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking_". If you care to [edit] your question it will get automatically queued for people to vote to reopen it.

Comment: Why putting keys under /etc/ssh is described clearly here https://help.ubuntu.com/community/SSH/OpenSSH/Keys#Troubleshooting
This link is in the question, and I told that I followed the procedure described there. I didn't put a specific question, because I wasn't sure what would be the correct question. Man, those who wanted to help were answering and asking questions below. You'd better ignore my question.

Comment: You have tagged with [tag:CentOS] and [tag:RHEL]. Why should anyone assume you're actually using Ubuntu? And if you're not using Ubuntu, but using an Ubuntu guide it becomes even more important to make it explicitly clear what it is that you're actually asking us.

Comment: I tried playing with permissions, but it didn't work. Than I saw someone on stackoverflow telling that the home directory might is encrypted and gave the link for Ubuntu solution. I started thinking that my home folder is encrypted too, so I followed the link. I'm on SentOS - no mistake here. I later put my keys back to home folder and ran restorecon command, and it worked. But, SSH creators advice not to keep keys in home directory...

Comment: OK. If you [edit] your question to include the output of this command run on the server, we can help you check the permissions, since that's what the log message is complaining about - `ls -ld / /etc /etc/ssh /etc/ssh/dmytrocx75 /etc/ssh/dmytrockx75/authorized_keys`

Answer (score 4):

The client side has successfully offered a RSA key, but the server side did not accept it. You'll need to look at the **server's** logs (typically `/var/log/secure` or `/var/log/auth.log`) to see why the key was rejected.

The rejection reason is not disclosed to the client, which is unauthenticated at this point and might be malicious. If you cannot access the server's logs, you'll need to contact the administrator of the server system, and ask them to check the logs for you.

A common reason for `sshd` ignoring a private key is unsafe permissions:

- your home directory on the server should be only writeable by yourself (permissions `drwxr-xr-x` or less)
- your `~/.ssh` directory on the server should only be accessible by yourself, and definitely not writeable by others (recommended permissions `drwx------`, maximum allowed by sshd is `drwxr-xr-x`)
- your `~/.ssh/authorized_keys` file on the server should only be accessible by yourself, and definitely not writeable by others (recommended permissions `-rw-------`, maximum allowed by sshd is `-rw-r--r--`)

If these constraints are not followed, `sshd` assumes the authorized_keys file has been tampered with by other users on the system (because the insecure permissions may have allowed it to happen) and will reject all key authentication attempts. That will result in `sshd` logging a message:

```
sshd[<PID>]: Authentication refused: bad ownership or modes for file <pathname>
```

Comment: The /var/log/auth.log doesn't exist in on my server, but added to the question the content of /var/log/secure.

Comment: Actually key file is in /etc/ssh/dmytrocx75/authorized_keys and
AuthorizedKeysFile   is set to   /etc/ssh/dmytrocx75/authorized_keys
Permissions are as you described

Comment: Could you please post the output of this command: `ls -ld / /etc /etc/ssh /etc/ssh/dmytrocx75 /etc/ssh/dmytrockx75/authorized_keys` ? If there is any directory with unsafe permissions along the path from `/` to the file, that would cause the error message you're getting. Also, you're apparently attempting to authenticate as `root`, not as user `dmytrocx75`. If you don't specify the target username with either `ssh -l user host` or `ssh user@host`, you'll be attempting to log in with the same username as you're currently logged in as on the client host.